# Can't map array from mongoose in React

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mongodb, mongoose

I want to map an array that's on a mongoose Schema: 
(dataNotes)

```
const {Schema, model} = require("mongoose");

const noteSchema= new Schema({
    idNote: {type: String, required: true, unique: true},
    dataNotes: [{
        title: {type:String, isRequired: true},
        authors: [{type: String, fecha: Date}] }]

}, {timestamps:true});

module.exports = model("noteSchema", noteSchema);
```

from the backend I respond the data with:

```
noteCtrl.getNoteInfo = async (req, res) => {
    await noteSchema.findOne({idNota: req.body.id})
        .then((response)=>{
            console.log(response)
            res.send(response);
        })
    console.log(req.body)

}
```

Here the data is sent fine, as an object

And my Frontend has:

```
    ObtNofNotes = async () => {
        await axios.post("http://localhost:4000/api/users/notes", {
            id:
                JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("user")).user
        })
            .then((res) => {
                console.log("Notes data " + res.data.dataNotes)
                //It only returns [object Object] for each array
                return this.notesArray(res.data.dataNotes)
            })
            .catch((err) => console.log(err));
    }

    notesArray= (n) => {
        n.map(nm => {
            console.log(nm)
            //it returns the arrays just fine
            return (<li>{nm.dataNotes[0][0]}</li>)
        })
    }
```

but when I want to render the li's with:

```
render() {
        return (
            <div>
                {this.ObtNofNotes()}
            </div>
        )
    }
```

React returns the error: "Objects are not valid as a React child (found: [object Promise]). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead."

But the data is already in an array, and when I console.log(nm) in the n.map() function, it returns each array and the objects inside it.

What am I doing wrong?

I supose that it has to do with the async functions and the promises because it renders this.ObtNofNotes(), an async function, and I'm not sure if it has  the data before rendering or if it waits the data before rendering, but i'm not sure. I'm new to React, and I will appreciate a lot your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it!
I did this:

I created an array in the component state:

```
state = {
   notes: []
}
```

Then in the function where I obtain the notes, I push the notes data on the notes state:

```
.then((res) => {
   this.setState({notes: res.data.dataNotes})
})
```

Then, in a componentDidMount function I called the asyncronous function that recives the data from the backend:

```
componentDidMount(){
        this.ObtNofNotes();
}
```

Then in the render function I map the notes array calling it from the state, and mapping it:

```
render() {

        return (
            <div>
                {
                this.state.notes.map(Data=>(
                <div>
                    <Note data= 
                        {Data}>
                    </Note>
                </div>
                ))}
            </div>
        )
    }
```

Hope this would help someone else!

Answer (score 0):

before you call `.then()` pass in a `.lean()` after the findOne query function.